# Update one MySQL table with values from another (Datatype of the original table is JSOn)

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I'm trying to update one MySQL table based on information from another.

The original table where I would like to compare the values to the other table to be updated has a JSON object in it.

Here is what my tables look like

Original Table

Table1

```
id | programme
------------
1  | ["22","34"]
2  | ["10","11","12","13","14","15","17","18","19","20"]
```

Table to be updated

Table2

```
id | programme_id | table1_id
-----------------------------
1  |     22       |
2  |     18       |
3  |     12       |


UPDATE table2
INNER JOIN table1 USING (programme_id)
SET table2.table1_id = table1.id
```

Here is the expected output:

```
id | programme_id | table1_id
-----------------------------
1  |     22       |   1
2  |     18       |   2
3  |     12       |   2
```

Comment: I was able to solve this with MySQL Inner Join

`UPDATE `table1` 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id 
SET `table1`.`programme_id` = table2.programme_id`

Answer (score 1):

```
set sql_safe_updates = 0;
update table2
inner join table1 
on JSON_SEARCH(table1.programme,'one',table2.programme_id) is not null
set table2.table1_id = table1.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however; I do not understand **JSON_SEARCH(table1.programme,'one',table2.programme_id)** what is **one** in the query. Do you mean **22** in my case and so on

Comment: JSON Data in your table1 is actually an array. Function JSON_SEARCH returns indexes values where the searched value is found. Argument 'one' returns only the index of the first occurence & the argument 'all' returns all the indexes where searched value exists. However, this is irrelevant to us, as we do not care about the index value, all we want to know if the searched value exist in our JSON column & its corresponding table1_id, thats it. **22** in your case is the **table2.programme_id** in my answer. Hope its clear now.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use another function to replace **JSON_SEARCH** is:                                 
    on JSON_CONTAINS(table1.programme,concat('"',table2.programme_id,'"')) = 1